# Backup the Windows user folder in the cloud?

Tags: dropbox, cloud-storage, google-drive

As I understand it, [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) and [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), the two cloud storage providers I happen to know, can only sync a predefined folder that is created upon installation.

I'd be happy to have an automated synchronisation of my folders in the cloud, but I'm not ready to change my habits, and start saving all my documents in the folder imposed by the provider.

Is it possible with one of these, or any other you might know, to sync the full Windows user folder instead?

Answer (score 0):

I know box.net does sync and you can sync whatever folder you want; however, I believe there are some limitations.

[Box.net Sync](https://www.box.com/business/features/box-sync/)

[The limitations](https://support.box.com/entries/20366301-box-sync-faq)

I don't know about Google Drive or Dropbox, but from your post it sounded like you weren't committed to either of those.

You can get 50GB account free if you have an HP Touchpad. I just opened one last week and got the 50GB deal free for life. After a few days the gave me the sync add-on (which is usually a paid app) for free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The biggest limitation from the link you provided is that it does not sync Outlook PST files, which for me is a blocker.

Answer (score 0):

[cubby](https://www.cubby.com/) should allow this - its unlimited sync between your own systems, and 5gb (+ up to 5 more based on referrals) of cloud storage. You should be able to sync any folders with a rightclick - I currently use it to have seperate 'repositories' of assignments.

Its currently invite only (I can e mail referrals, but a direct signup only takes, at most a week), and works really well.